# "With his closed eyes" vs "With his eyes closed"

Tags: grammar

Context: (Sherlock Holmes and the Duke's Son / Oxford University Press)

> He was a large man, tall, well-dressed, and important-looking, He came
>   into the room, walked to one of the big chairs, and suddenly fell into
>   it. He sat there, **with his eyes closed**, looking white and ill.

Can we say **"with his closed eyes"**? instead of that sentence.
And what's the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is that one sounds natural and the other sounds a little off. If he sits there "with his closed eyes" it evokes an image of some other set of eyes that he has in a box or on a tray or something.

Comment: @Robusto: I couldn't find a related *closed eyes* context, but [*"You are so narrow-minded! You're probably Republican! They're so tunnel-visioned! I'll go alone and you can stay home **with your closed mind,** since you don't like my friends," she yelled.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+are+so+narrow-minded!+You%27re+probably+Republican%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) sounds pretty "natural" to me.

Comment: @Fumble: The two are different. You can't really reason by analogy here.

Comment: @Robusto: Of course they're "different". But my "implicitly condemnatory" connotation is far more likely than that adjectival *closed* is a "restrictive" usage implying he has *other* eyes that aren't closed! :) Whatever - I think this question belongs on ELL, and the only answer here so far is *wrong*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure it is 'wrong'. If the thing he does with his 'closed eyes' is refuse to see something, either physical or metaphysical. *With his closed eyes, and closed mind, he refused to accept that he was the cause of family misery'. I shall up vote the answer.

Comment: @Robusto May I have your attention for a moment, Please. I will delete my comment soon. Thanks.

Comment: @Afsane: What part of my attention do you require?

Comment: @Robusto Sorry, but I asked you and FumbleFingers and WS2 to answer my question that is quite related to OP's question. And the question is: Is it wrong to use *with your closed eye/ eyes* or  *with closed eye/eyes*. If not. what are the differences between *with your eye/ eyes closed* or *with eye/eyes closed * AND *with your eye/eyes closed* or *with eye/eyes closed*.

Comment: @Afsane: I think this has been thoroughly discussed by this point, and there is an accepted answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are slightly different meanings.

He did something "with his eyes closed" means that his eyes were closed while doing it.

He did something "with his closed eyes" means that he used those closed eyes in doing it.

Since there isn't much you can do with your closed eyes, the term isn't used much.

Comment: As I mention above, I am upvoting. But I think you need to make clear that the thing he does with his 'closed eyes' may simply be to refuse to see.

Answer (score 1):

"With his closed eyes" might imply a permanent or long-term condition that caused his eyes to be closed.  In that specific sentence, I'd read "with his closed eyes" to mean that his eyes were also closed while he came into the room and fell into the chair, possibly because he was blind or had a muscle disorder of his eyelids.

It does not mean the same as "with his eyes closed".

Comment: In similar constructs no permanence is implied.  "He slapped him with his tired hand" is valid, and the hand won't stay tired for long.

Comment: @DJClayworth "He slapped him with his tired hand" doesn't make any sense to me either way.  Also, I'm not talking about similar constructs.  I'm talking about that specific sentence in that specific paragraph, as that's what OP was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

When the clause describes him, use 'with his eyes closed'  .

When the clause describes 'eyes ' , use 'with his closed eyes' . e.g. "With his closed eyes, he could see for miles. "